# Global Entry Renewal and Card Replacement

Tags: global-entry

I renewed my Global Entry membership. The ttp web site gives the impression that they are not sending me a new card, even though my existing one has an expiration date on the face.

To ask for a new card requires giving a reason none of which are true.

Has anyone else done this process? Will I, in fact, receive a new card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I renewed my GE membership in February 2022.

A week or two later, I received a new GE card in the mail.

Comment: I renewed just a week ago and was told to expect a new card within 6 weeks.